# get pointer to QListWidget -- from QListWidgetItem

Tags: qt

I am having `QListWidgetItem * item` pointing to an item in QListWidget.

How can i get **pointer to** QListWidget from **QListWidgetItem** ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not a crowdsourced documentation lookup service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `item->listWidget()`. Simple.